# How to return URLs based on HATEOAS without modifying the whole response?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, hateoas

I have developed a service using Spring Boot. This is the code (simplified):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
public class CarController {
    @Autowired
    private CarService carService;

    @Autowired
    private CarMapper carMapper;

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public CarDto findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Car car = carService.findById(id);
        return carMapper.mapToCarDto(car);
    }
}
```

`CarMapper` is defined using mapstruct. Here's the code (simplified as well):

```
@Mapper(componentModel="spring",
        uses={ MakeModelMapper.class })
public interface CarMapper {
    @Mappings({
        //fields omitted
        @Mapping(source="listaImagenCarro", target="rutasImagenes")
    })
    CarDto mapToCarDto(Car car);

    String CAR_IMAGE_URL_FORMAT = "/cars/%d/images/%d"
    /*
        MapStruct will invoke this method to map my car image domain object into a String. Here's my issue.
    */
    default String mapToUrl(CarImage carImage) {
        if (carImage == null) return null;
        return String.format(
                   CAR_IMAGE_URL_FORMAT,
                   carImage.getCar().getId(),
                   carImage.getId()
               );
    }
}
```

The JSON response I get when invoking the service:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "make": { ... },
    "model": { ... },
    //more fields...
    //the urls for the car images
    "images": [
        "/cars/9/images/1"
    ]
}
```

I need that the `images` field returns valid URLs regarding the server and path where my app is deployed. For example, if I deploy the app using localhost through port 8080, I would like to get this:

```
{
    "id": 9,
    "make": { ... },
    "model": { ... },
    //more fields...
    "imagenes": [
        "http://localhost:8080/cars/9/images/1"
    ]
}
```

I've reviewed [Building a Hypermedia-Driven RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-hateoas/), which seems what I want. Except that I only need it for these urls, I don't want to change my whole response object.

Is there another way to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring HATEOAS provides a LinkBuilder service just for this purpose.

Try the following:

```
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo;
import static org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn;
//...//

linkTo(methodOn(CarController.class).findById(9)).withRel("AddYourRelHere");
```

This should output an absolute URL that points to your resource. You are not following the [HAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Application_Language) convention, so you should change or remove the part "withRel("")"

You can add this to the specific DTOs you want to change:

```
CarDto dto = carMapper.mapToCarDto(car);
if(dto.matches(criteria)){
    dto.setUrl(linkTo...);
}
return dto;
```

By the way, all of this is shown in the section "Create a RestController" of the tutorial you mention.